# How to pause the video at exact predefined time in video.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

We are working on a video editing project and we need to pause the video at pre-specified times.

Like, there is a 100 sec video that needs to stop exactly at 11.2431 sec, 36.0794 sec, 55.6834, 92.3541 sec, and 98.5255 sec.

We have already tried below:

```
var pausetime = 36.0794; // stop at 36.0794 seconds

var myPlayer = videojs('example_video_1');

myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if (myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime) {
        myPlayer.pause();
    }
});

myPlayer.play();
```

But, it will never be going to stop at the exact time we specified. We are ok even if we manage to stop it at 36.07 or 36.08 smoothly.

Comment: I think the problem lies that `timeupdate` does not fire at such rapid intervals that allows you to pinpoint down to a fraction of a millisecond. The event is fired when the browser has the resources to do so, and regular intervals and millisecond precision cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: There is usually a delta of 200ms to 300ms before the next event is fired for `timeupdate` the best way to handle this logic is by adding a certain delta to your if condition logic like `myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime - 0.2`. And by the way this is not guaranteed to behave as it should. The suggestion is simply a hack

Comment: @SumitSurana Thanks for the suggestions. The current logic is already working like that and update the current time once paused. Which is not really for a smooth experience on iOS browsers.